# Show an error message if a TextBox value is higher than a specific cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, compare, cell

Like the title say, I want to verify an entry and compare it with a specific cell (iLastRow, 8). 
For that, I put this lign before my others conditions.

```
        Test = (TextBox2.Text) > ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8)
      If Test = True Then
            MsgBox "Not enough quantity in stock!"
      Else
```

But the message is showing every time, even if the number is lower.
The strange thing is that the code works well if all the cell between column 4 to 7 are filled and doesn't work anymore if I erase the content of more than 2 side rows. 
There's my whole code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Enter()

  Dim emptyRow As Long

  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  ActiveSheet.Name = "Micrux"

  Dim iLastRow As Long, iFound As Long

  Dim rng, bEmpty As Boolean, c As Integer

  Dim Test As Boolean

  bEmpty = True


   With ws

      iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & iLastRow + 1).Find(ComboBox1.Value, _

        After:=.Range("A" & iLastRow + 1), _

        LookIn:=xlValues, _

        lookat:=xlWhole, _

        searchorder:=xlByRows, _

        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)


      Test = (TextBox2.Text) > ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8)

    If Test = True Then

      MsgBox "Not enough quantity in stock!"

    Else

   If rng Is Nothing Then

       iFound = iLastRow + 1

   Else
       iFound = rng.Row

       For c = 4 To 7
         If Len(.Cells(iFound, c)) > 0 Then bEmpty = False
       Next

       If bEmpty = False Then
          iFound = iFound + 1
         .Cells(iFound, 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

          .Cells(iFound, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
          .Cells(iFound, 6).Value = TextBox3.Text
          .Cells(iFound, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
          .Cells(iFound, 4).Value = TextBox1.Text

     Else
          .Cells(iFound, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
          .Cells(iFound, 6).Value = TextBox3.Text
          .Cells(iFound, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
          .Cells(iFound, 4).Value = TextBox1.Text
      End If

  End If

       End If

End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Test =VAL(TextBox2.Text) > VAL(ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8).Value)`

Comment: Thanks Siddhart Rout, it works with iFound but not with the same row as iLastRow, it just doesn't show the message..

Comment: Step through the code and check what is the value of `iLastRow` and `ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8).Value` and `TextBox2.Text`

Comment: Finally it doesn't work unless I put really high value..

Comment: Did you see my  last message?

Comment: Yes sorry, I don't know how to do that.. 

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: Do you mean iRow is 8 or ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8) = 8 ? What is the last row in Column A  and col H?

Comment: Yes it was! And by that information I finally find the problem, I needed to replace iLastRow by iFound!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem and I changed a part of the code for that:

```
      iFound = rng.Row
        Test = Val(TextBox2.Text) > ws.Cells(iFound, 8).Value
      If Test = True Then
        MsgBox "Not enough quantity in stock!"
      Else
```

It works pretty well and it's a lot because of your help Siddharth Rout!!!!